# Hibernate batch insert

Tags: hibernate, jdbc

This is my code to insert batch in database

```
  @Override
  public void addMultiple(){

    session = get_session();
  tx = session.beginTransaction();
 for ( int i=0; i<100; i++ ) {
 Person person = new Person();
 person.setName("oll"+i);
 session.save(person);
 if( i % 20 == 0 ) { // Same as the JDBC batch size
    //flush a batch of inserts and release memory:
    session.flush();
    session.clear();
   }
}
tx.commit();
session.close();
}
```

this is my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file

```
 <property  name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?rewriteBatchedStatements=true</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="format_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.order_inserts">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

but after insert operation i can see query is printed in console is

```
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
  Hibernate: insert into Person (name) values (?)
```

That means it doesn't insert batch. My entity has no identifier generation. So what is the problem? Why can't I insert batch?

My Entity class are

```
  @Entity
  public class Person {

   @Id
   public String name;

    public String getName() {
    return name;
     }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }




 }
```

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Did you try using `profileSQL` parameter to check if MySQL driver rewrites statements?

Answer (score 3):

Very probably you are actually using batching, it is just that Hibernate prints sql for each statement.

To check this, enable DEBUG log level for `org.hibernate` package (and TRACE level for `org.hibernate.type` if you want to see bound variables), then check if following appears in the log:

- Reusing batch statement
- Executing batch size

If a number larger than 1 is printed for executed batch size, then you are using batching.

Specific to MySQL, to make sure that MySQL driver rewrites insert statements, enable `profileSQL` parameter in connection url as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530112/no-matter-what-i-cant-batch-mysql-insert-statements-in-hibernate).

**NOTE:** JDBC batching is [disabled](http://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-identity-sequence-and-table-sequence-generator/) if IDENTITY id generator is used.

I also suggest that you consider setting `hibernate.order_updates` to true, to improve batching of update statements as well. A nice summary about this Hibernate tuning is described [here](http://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-batch-insert-and-update-statements-with-hibernate/).