# Spring Data Batch Inserts

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data

I've been trying to enable Batch Inserts using Spring Boots JPA with a MySQL database

In my **application.properties**:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo?reconnect=true&rewriteBatchedStatements=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.jdbc.batch_size=500
spring.jpa.hibernate.order_inserts=true
spring.datasource.username=demo_user
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

I have tried using both `CrudRepository.save(Iterable s)` and have tried using a custom repository (which i've seen in another answer):

```
@Component
public class BulkRepository<T extends Identifiable> {// Identifiable just has a getId method

    private static final int BATCH_SIZE = 500;

    private final EntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    public BulkRepository(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Transactional
    public <S extends T> List<S> saveInBatch(Iterable<S> value) {
        List<S> entities = Lists.newArrayList(value);
        List<S> saved = new ArrayList<>(entities.size());
        int i = 0;
        for (S t : entities) {
            saved.add(persistOrMerge(t));
            i++;
            if (i % BATCH_SIZE == 0) {
                // Flush a batch of inserts and release memory.
                entityManager.flush();
                entityManager.clear();
            }
        }

        return saved;
    }

    private <S extends T> S persistOrMerge(S t) {
        if (t.getId() == null) {
            entityManager.persist(t);
            return t;
        } else {
            return entityManager.merge(t);
        }
    }
}
```

When I enable the general query log in MySql with both the above it shows each insert as seperate:

```
SET GLOBAL log_output = 'TABLE';
SET GLOBAL general_log = 'ON';

SELECT 
    event_time,
    user_Host,
    CONVERT(argument USING utf8) as query
FROM mysql.general_log
order by event_time desc
;
```

> 2017-12-22 12:31:48.290334    demo_user[demo_user] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]    insert
> into demo.test_table (id, string) values (1, 'value1')
>
> 2017-12-22 12:31:48.288328    demo_user[demo_user] @ localhost [127.0.0.1]    insert into
> demo.test_table (id, string) values (2, 'value2')

Is there something I'm missing? At the moment it is looking like I'll need to bypass Spring JPA and use raw SQL for this.

Comment: No it isn't... The JDBC driver is rewriting the batch statements not hibernate in this case. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530112/no-matter-what-i-cant-batch-mysql-insert-statements-in-hibernate/21587949#21587949

Comment: @M.Deinum Thats not how they appear in the MySQL log though (which is direct from the database itself)

Comment: To me it looks like what you posted is the application log not the mysql log. Nonetheless the answer is in the same question.

Comment: @M.Deinum The log is from running the query above it direct via MySql workbench

Comment: I think the question is different, I cant call `Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();` like they are using as my transactionals are managed by `@Transactional`. I get an exception if I try use both within the same application.

Comment: Your `spring.jpa.hibernate` properties are pretty much useless. It should be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate....`

Comment: No the question isn't different, how a transaction is started doesn't matter. The fact is that hibernate will always log single queries.

Comment: @M.Deinum as mentioned, that is not the hibernate log (i'm aware that always logs single queries). It is the result of running the SQL query in my question above.

Comment: Always nice if people skip your comments -> Your `spring.jpa.hibernate properties` are pretty much useless. It should be `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161819/discussion-between-edd-and-m-deinum).